# Is there a way to rotate a shader?

Tags: shader, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a mirror shader to my scene, which is working with the exception of the reflection being upside down in the mirror. Is there a way I can modify the script or shader so that it's aligned properly?

I'm using the Mirror [Reflection 4 shader](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MirrorReflection4).

I'm not able (at least currently) to change the math data.

Thanks :)

Update: Around line 47, I changed `Vector3 normal = transform.up;` to `Vector3 normal = transform.right;` and it's rotated correction, but reflecting the wrong side. It's also flipping the reflection, but maybe it's a start.

Edit: Turns out it was because the local transform was changed in Maya.